# Why 10 & (!5) return zero?

Tags: c++, math, binary

I have been trying following code with c++ and I can't figure it out why this return zero.

`10 & (!5)`
We know 10 in binary is 1010 and 5 is 0101 and not(5) is 1010.
Let's go with this:

```
1010  //Which represent 10
1010  //Which represent not(5)
------AND
1010
```

This should actually return 10 not zero. Am I wrong ?

Comment: `!5` is `false` which converts to `0`.

Comment: Use a simpler program to find out what the value of `!5` actually is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `!` is boolean negation, not bitwise negation, so you've effectively said `10 & 0`.

You'd be better off trying `10 & ~5`